# Application.OnTime stops firing after changing the active document

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to implement an autosave function for all documents created from a certain template. In this template I have created the following for tests:

```
Dim doc As Document
Dim count As Integer

Private Sub Document_Open()
count = 1
Set doc = ActiveDocument
SaveTime
End Sub

Sub SaveTime()
Application.OnTime When:=Now + TimeValue("00:00:15"), _
name:="DoSave"
End Sub

Sub DoSave()
doc.SaveAs2 "c:\test\testsave" & count & ".docx"
count = count + 1
SaveTime
End Sub
```

Now if I open a document thats created by this template the autosaving works every 15 seconds as intended (15sec + the counter with different name is just for testing).

BUT as soon as I create a new document in Word or open another file the autosaving in the first document stops working and also doesnt come back if I continue to work in the document.

How can I make the autosave work no matter of which document is active? Like this the feature would only work if only one Document is open at a time, which I can not garantuee of course.

Answer (score 0):

Shot in the dark here, but you are dimming doc within the scope of the module (from what I can tell). It is possible that opening the new document causes this to go out of scope. It would be best to just pass the document between routines.

Something like this:

```
' This will declare count within the scope of the module
Private count As Integer

Private Sub Document_Open()
    count = 1
    SaveTime ActiveDocument
End Sub

Sub SaveTime(doc as Document)
    Application.OnTime When:=Now + TimeValue("00:00:15"), "'DoSave doc'"
End Sub

Sub DoSave(doc as Document)
    doc.SaveAs2 "c:\test\testsave" & count & ".docx"
    count = count + 1
    SaveTime
End Sub
```

I haven't used OnTime much, so if the syntax above doesnt allow arguments to be passed, here is a version using a Private doc variable.

```
' This will declare count and doc within the scope of the module
Private count As Integer
Private doc as Document

Private Sub Document_Open()
    count = 1
    SaveTime
End Sub

Sub SaveTime()
    Application.OnTime When:=Now + TimeValue("00:00:15"), "DoSave"
End Sub

Sub DoSave()
    doc.SaveAs2 "c:\test\testsave" & count & ".docx"
    count = count + 1
    SaveTime
End Sub
```

I hope this helps. I mostly work within Excel for VBA so I apologize if I am way off the mark here.

EDIT:

I figured it out. What is happening is every time your save event fires it is saving the active document as a new file, but it is not creating a new instance. For example, if test is your first document then:

Test Opens > Event Fires > Test becomes Test2.docx ( Event Fires > Test2 becomes Test3 etc.

Since the code is still stored in memory somehow (this is the part I dont fully understand, but it is, from what I can tell, is what's happening) the event still fires. The problem is, opening a new document somehow refreshes this and the event cancels.

There is a simple workaround, see below:

```
Option Explicit
Private doc As Document
Private count As Integer
Private Sub Document_Open()
    count = 1
    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    SaveTime
End Sub
Sub SaveTime()
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:15"), "DoSave"
End Sub

Sub DoSave()
    doc.Save
    Application.Documents.Add doc.FullName

    ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 "c:\test\testsave" & count & ".docx"
    ActiveDocument.Close

    count = count + 1
    SaveTime
End Sub
```

This creates a new instance of the document, saves this new instance, and then closes it. This leaves the old instance in-tact and running.

I hope that all makes sense. Admittedly, I am not clear on why the code remains in memory even when the document holding the code no longer exists.

Comment: Thanks for the help Brandon,
I did try your variant2 but it didn't make a difference. About Variant1 i am also not sure about passing a nonstring parameter, I will try to search about this but I think its not whats the problem here. 
Actually the DoSave Sub doesnt get triggered anymore after I change documents, its not the saving that fails. It looks like the OnTime somehow gets cancelled completely.

Comment: I created a test routine within word and I am unable to reproduce the problem. I set the same kind of loop and just had it print to the console every five seconds. After opening, saving, and closing a document I didnt have any issues. I also didnt have any issues if I overwrote the document I opened, saved and closed. This leads me to believe that there is something we are missing within your code, and not within the OnTime method.

Comment: See my edit. The problem is that the file with the code was being overwritten and thus the code no longer existed to run. I added code to create a new instance of the document and debugging it worked just fine.